# iPhone Email client includes wrong Original Message in body of reply

Tags: iphone, email, ios, mobile-mail

I'm using an iPhone 6, running iOS 9.2.1. Recently, I experienced an issue with my iPhone email client. I hit "Reply All" on an **Email A**, composed my reply message, and hit "Send," but the email that was sent had some very incorrect information.

The subject line in my reply email was correct: "Re: Subject A," and the sent message included the reply text that I had composed, but the Original Message (the text that is automatically included below my signature when I reply to an email) that the email client included in the reply was NOT **Email A**. It was a bizarre combination of **Email A** and a separate message, **Email B**, which happened to be the most recent email I had received. To illustrate, here is what the situation looked like:

---

## EMAIL A

From: **Person A**
Sent: Wednesday, June 1, 2016 12:00 PM **(Date/Time A)**
To: Me
Subject: **Subject A**

*"Message Text A"*

**PERSON A**'s SIGNATURE

## EMAIL B

*(Completely unrelated to **Email A**)*
From: **Person B**
Sent: Wednesday, June 1, 2016 12:10 PM **(Date/Time B)**
To: Me
Subject: **Subject B**

*"Message Text B"*

**PERSON B**'s SIGNATURE

## EMAIL C

*(My email in reply to **Email A**—this should have only included data from **Email A**)*
From: Me
Sent: Wednesday, June 1, 2016 12:15 PM (Date/Time C)
To: **Person A**
Subject: Re: **Subject A**

*"Message Text C"*

MY SIGNATURE
*[Auto-populated reply header:]* On Jun 1, 2016, at 12:10 PM **(Date/Time B)**, **Person A** wrote:

***"Message Text B"***

---

I'm baffled by what could have caused this. As you can imagine, this caused some miscommunication, including some severe privacy concerns, and I cannot have this happen again.

It seems like when the email client was preparing Email C for me to enter my reply, it may have somehow linked Email B to Email A. Any ideas on what could have caused this, or what may have happened?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and it turned out to be related the the "threading" of conversations. Turns out it was grouping everything with the same subject and grabbing a random one to reply to. Turn off threading and conversation grouping in settings and this problem went away.